# Spring MVC - pagination and request methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Let's say I have this controller:

```
import org.java.wsg.service.ClientsService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.support.PagedListHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller
public class ClientsController {

    @Autowired
    ClientsService clientsService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/clients.htm")
    public String clientsPage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        PagedListHolder pagedList = new PagedListHolder(clientsService.getClients());
        pagedList.setPageSize(50);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("clientsList", pagedList);

        model.addAttribute("clients", pagedList.getPageList());

        return "clients";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/clientsNavigate.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String clientsNavigateToPage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model,
                                        @RequestParam String action) {

        PagedListHolder pagedList = (PagedListHolder) request.getSession().getAttribute("clientsList");

        if (action.equals("next")) {
            pagedList.nextPage();

        } else if (action.equals("previous")) {
            pagedList.previousPage();
        }

        model.addAttribute("clients", pagedList.getPageList());

        return "clients";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/clients/{id}.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String clientById(Model model, @PathVariable Integer id, HttpServletRequest request) {

        PagedListHolder pagedList = new PagedListHolder(clientsService.getClientById(id));
        pagedList.setPageSize(50);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("clientsList", pagedList);

        model.addAttribute("clients", pagedList.getPageList());

        return "clients";
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is an `clients.jsp` page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Clients</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="<c:url value='/resources/css/bootstrap.css'/>"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.js" />">

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" />">

    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">

        <div class="span10 offset1">
            <center>
                <h2>Clients</h2>
            </center>

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <center>Id</center>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <center>Ip</center>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <center>Connections</center>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <center>GUID</center>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <center>Name</center>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <center>Group</center>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <center>Time added</center>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <center>Last seen</center>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach items="${clients}" var="c">
                    <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${c.id}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${c.ip}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${c.connections}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${c.guid}"/></td>
                        <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/clients/${c.id}.htm"><c:out
                                value="${c.name}"/></a>
                        </td>
                        <td><c:out value="${c.group}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${c.timeAdd}"/></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${c.timeEdit}"/></td>

                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
            <form:form method="post" action="clientsNavigate.htm">
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="previous" class="btn btn-info" />
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="next" class="btn btn-info" />

            </form:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you may see, first method (clientsPage) fetches list of i.e. `Client` objects and pass them as an attribute to `clients.jsp` page. Second method (clientsNavigateToPage) is used to process form request (simple form with two buttons (`Next` and `Previous`)) in `clients.jsp` page. And third method is used to obtain multiple clients with some id. But problem I'm facing is after I process my `/clients/{id}.htm` request I can't process my `/clientsNavigate.htm` request.

It says: 
`HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported`

How to deal with this issue?

Comment: please include your HTML (or whatever is used to send the form) code.

Comment: have you checked if form `action` is correct, i.e. that request is sent to the right controller?
Try removing `method = RequestMethod.POST` from your mapping. Although this seems to be correct, let us check if removing it helps.

Comment: @MichałRybak Just checked. Yes, it's sent to right controller.

Comment: Did removing `method = RequestMethod.POST` help?

Comment: @MichałRybak No, it didn't.

Comment: This is weird. Make sure changes in your code are reflected on server. You can also try changing form `action` to GET for a while (and check if it will really send GET request - if not, you are not running right code).

Comment: Already tried with GET. Didn't help too. And yes, it is weird. Since it works with `clientsPage` method and it doesn't work when `clientById` is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because every thing else looks not like a bug, I think the only remaining problem is the form url.

For your links you use this pattern:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/clients/${c.id}.htm">...</a>
```

But for the page nav you use this relative url

```
<form:form method="post"
           action="clientsNavigate.htm"
```

So I think it would be worth trying:

```
<form:form method="post"
           action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/clientsNavigate.htm" ...
```

---

*Btw: I would recommend to use `c:url`  (without contextPath but starts with slash) instead*

```
<c:url var="navFormUrl" value= "/clientsNavigate.htm" />
<form:form method="post" action="${navFormUrl}" ...
```

Comment: OP says in comment that request is sent to the right controller, so I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Michał Rybak: "How often have I said to you that when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth?" Sherlock Holmes, by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle. ;-) -- And from my experience at stack overflow, I have to say, that if you have a program and a OP, and both tell you something different, most time the code is the one that does not lie.