# JDBC.SQLServerException: The result set has no current row

Tags: java, exception, jpa, jdbc, resultset

So, a solution I created threw this exception: `jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set has no current row` on the line marked in the below code.

```
public String get64BitEncodedImageBySiteID(int siteID){
    try {           
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT SitePicture FROM SiteTable WHERE SiteID ="+siteID );

        rs.next();
        // The above line has since been moved to the if statement below where you can see it commented out,
        // which prevents the exception from occuring but still doesn't fix the fact that the row is not being found. 

        if(/*rs.next() &&*/ rs.getBytes("SitePicture")!=null){ // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE!
            byte ba[] = rs.getBytes("SitePicture");            
            return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(ba);
        }
        else {return null;}
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The method above, in the instance the exception was thrown, is taking a genuine siteID (22379) from an Entity object pulled directly from the same table. When using `System.out.println(siteID);` during this method, it declared that number to still be correct, ie still 22379. I've checked directly with the SQL server by running an identical statement in SQL Server, so I know the row exists in the table, but for some reason it is not being found. Image below.

[image]

So the problem is, the ResultsSet `rs` is not finding the row even though I know that it's there. Does anyone have any helpful insights?

Clarification: *Just to be clear, I know that the ResultsSet contains no rows and that is why I am getting the exception. I also know that putting the rs.next() into the if statement will prevent the exception (as already stated in the comments). What is puzzling me is that the fact the ResultsSet contains no rows even though a row with the ID being parsed to it verifiably does exists because I have checked it directly with the SQL server.*

Comment: @JunedAhsan it should be `rs.next()` I think,`rs.hasNext()` is not present in resultset

Comment: @downvoter - If there is an issue with my question I need to know what it is. A downvote on it's own is not helpful.

Comment: did you try putting a constant value instead of `siteID`? Like `SELECT SitePicture FROM SiteTable WHERE SiteID = 42` or whatever yields correct results when executed directly on SQL server.

Comment: @MichałRybak - Actually, this particular problem is only happening with the ID from one site, as far as I am aware, and is happening correctly on every other occasion. So, yes, it has been tried with other values and is working correctly.

Comment: and what is the value of this (failing) `SiteID`? Do you null-check it? Looks like there is some problem not related to code, but rather the data itself or the way you verify results.

Comment: @MichałRybak - I am afraid there is nothing remarkable about the ID. It's just a 4 digit integer. `2184`

Comment: And `SELECT SitePicture FROM SiteTable WHERE SiteID = 2184` (with 2184  hardcoded) doesn't work in your code, but works when entered directly into SQL server? Are you **sure** your code queries the same database?

Comment: Positive. I just double checked it (although 2184 is the wrong number). I will update the question shortly with screen shots etc.

Comment: @MichałRybak - Looks like I screwed up. You were right, I shouldn't have been sure that I was querying the correct DB. I use JPA and JDBC in this solution separately and the JPA connection details were correct but the JDBC were being parsed values from the old test DB, which didn't have this entry. If you could find a way to phrase that as an answer that could be helpful to others, then I will up-vote and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be a local mistake, but I'll post the solution anyway because this situation has some educational value.

As I've learned from @Ralph's comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20161896/spring-mvc-pagination-and-request-methods/20162675#20162675), eliminating "the impossible" is a good way for such problems.

After avoiding the risk of `siteID` being wrong (by hardcoding it), we have a following situation:

- the **same exact query** worked in one environment, but not the other, for only one particular `SiteID`, 2184
- it's impossible that `ResultSet` just *doesn't work* for *this particular value* (I *claim* it is, because I always assume errors are in *my* code, not in language libraries)
- if so, the databases **must differ**

Comment: I faced the same issue today. but discovered that without if (rs.next) condition it got failed and when added this condition it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Adding result statements inside while loop helped in my case.
`while(rs.next) {
rs.getString("your column name");
}`

Answer (score 3):

The most likely explanation is that your ResultSet contains no rows. Have you checked that?

If that's the case, `rs.next()` will return false, but you are not checking the return value any more. Put `rs.next()` back into the if block, it was OK in there.

You can make sure by:

```
if (rs.next()) {

  if(rs.getBytes("SitePicture")!=null){ 
     byte ba[] = rs.getBytes("SitePicture");            
     return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(ba);
  }

} else {

   System.out.println("No rows returned");

}
```

EDIT:

what column type is siteID?
Your method takes an int, but your SQL wraps it in quotes, as if it were a string.

EDIT 2:

Using a PreparedStatement might solve your problem.

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT SitePicture FROM SiteTable WHERE SiteID = ?");
ps.setInt(1, siteId);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Instead of putting the parameter directly into the SQL string (not recommended anyway), try using parameter placeholders in a prepared statement: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Edited my answer to include PreparedStatement example

Answer (score 1):

You may not get the result without checking whether the result has entries. For that use

```
while(rs.next()){
  rs.getString("column name");
}
```

and try it. It worked fine for me.

Thanks