# SQLServerException: The result set has no current row

Tags: java, html, sql

Running into the following 500 error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set has no
>   current row.

I checked and I even have the `rs.next()` to push it to the next row.
Not sure why it is not pulling the `QtyAvail`
My table is called `Inventory` and it has a primary key of `ProductID` and an attribute called `QtyAvail`.

```
<%@page import="beans.Products"%>
 <%@page import="java.lang.String"%>

 <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
  <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
  <%@page import="beans.ItemLine"%>
     <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>

    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:useBean id="cart" class="beans.CartItems" scope="session"/>
     <%    //set up the Producst object
       int QtyAvail = 0;
       Products product = new Products();

       String ProductID = request.getParameter("ProductID");

       String productDescription = request.getParameter("Decscription");
       String productQty = request.getParameter("ProductQty");
       String productPrice = request.getParameter("ProductPrice");
       String ProductName = request.getParameter("ProductName");

    try{
        //ger inv from SQL and make sure we have enough
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://clay.student.ad.fgcu.edu:1433;databaseName=ISM4154PartIteam02;user=4154Team02;password=Fgcu02;");    
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("Select QtyAvail from Inventory where ProductID=?");
        ps.setString(1, ProductID);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        rs.next();

        QtyAvail = rs.getInt("QtyAvail");

         System.out.println(QtyAvail); 

        ps.close();
        conn.close();  //Close the connections.

    //Check that we have enough quantity on hand
       `if(Integer.parseInt(productQty) <= QtyAvail) {

      //a new LineItem is created and Attributes are set
        ItemLine item = new ItemLine();
        item.setProduct(product);



        product.setProductDescription(productDescription);

        item.setProductDescription(productDescription);

        product.setProductQuantity(Integer.parseInt(productQty));
        item.setProductQuantity(Integer.parseInt(productQty));

        product.setProductPrice(Double.parseDouble(productQty));

        item.setProductPrice(Double.parseDouble(productPrice));


        cart.addItem(item);
            //passes page to cart jsp
       response.sendRedirect("CustomerCart.jsp");
        }
      else { 
           %>
           <h3> Sorry!  we only have currently" <%out.println(QtyAvail);%> "of <%out.println(ProductName);%>  in Inventory </h3> 

           <h3> Please select a quantity amount we have in Inventory </h3>
        <input type="button" name="continue" value="Continue Shopping" onclick="window.location='homePage.html'"> 
             <%   }

    //} 
  //catch(Exception e){       
     //out.println("404 System Not Found");

             // }

  %>      


    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Does this help -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900819/jdbc-sqlserverexception-the-result-set-has-no-current-row ?